# Automatically paraphrasing sentences in Java

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I'm trying to automatically paraphrase text using regular expressions.

So I'll need to find a way to replace the first match of a regular expression with a randomly generated match of that regular expression, like this:

```
public static String paraphraseUsingRegularExpression(String textToParaphrase, String regexToUse){
    //In textToParaphrase, replace the first match of regexToUse with a randomly generated match of regexToUse, and return the modified string.
}
```

So how can I replace the first match of a regular expression in a string with a randomly generated match of that regular expression? (Perhaps a library called [xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/) would be useful for this purpose.)

For example, `paraphraseUsingRegularExpression("I am very happy today", "(very|extremely) (happy|joyful) (today|at this (moment|time|instant in time))");` would replace the first match of the regular expression with a randomly generated match of the regular expression, which could produce the output `"I am extremely joyful at this moment in time"`, or `"I am very happy at this time"`.

Comment: A library called [xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/) might be useful in this case.

Comment: Instead of posting comments under your own question just [[edit]] it with that additional information.

Comment: You should construct the regex from a set of equivalent words, then generate the regex, and then choose the word during replacement. You will need to parse the regex yourself if you starts from the regex alone.

Comment: If you might find the library useful - did you try?

Comment: IMO unless you have a *very* limited input, doing this via regex is a Really Bad Idea and will essentially never work. That may be what you're trying to do, in which case, okay, but... good luck with that.

Comment: Oh, I believe I misunderstood your usage of the word "paraphrasing", which generally means "express the same meaning in a different way", which this is not. Is it critical that your input sentence be explicitly human-readable, or could you use placeholders, and provide pluggable mechanisms for generating their value? That seems like an easier way to handle this.

Comment: @Howard No, the idea of using xeger didn't occur to me before. I'll see if I can get it to work this way.

Comment: @DaveNewton If automatically paraphrasing sentences using regexes seems like a bad idea, then can you think of a better approach to the same problem? (Do you mean that automatically paraphrasing sentences is a bad idea, and that I shouldn't even try to solve this problem)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Paraphrasing is part of NLP, which is Hard. What you're doing here isn't paraphrasing, it's madlibs.

Comment: I think there are some professional language processing libraries you could find at google.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the steps below:

First, split the `textToParaphrase` string with `regexToUse` and you will get an array with the portions of the `textToParaphrase` doesn't matched with the provided expression. For example: if,

```
 textToParaphrase = "I am very happy today for you";
 regexToUse = "(very|extremely) (happy|joyful) (today|at this (moment|time|instant in time))";
```

The output will be : `{"I am ", "for you"}`.
Then create a regular expression with these generated strings (like `"(I am |for you)"`). Now again split the `textToParaphrase` with this generated expression and you will get the array of the matched portions of the given regular expression. And finally you replace each of the matched portion with the randomly generated string.

The code is like bellow:

```
public static String paraphraseUsingRegularExpression(String textToParaphrase, String regexToUse){
    String[] unMatchedPortionArray = textToParaphrase.split(regexToUse);
    String regExToFilter = "(";
    for(int i = 0; i< unMatchedPortionArray.length; i++){
        if(i == unMatchedPortionArray.length -1){
            regExToFilter+=unMatchedPortionArray[i];
        } else {
            regExToFilter+=unMatchedPortionArray[i]+"|";
        }
    }
    regExToFilter+=")";

    String[] matchedPortionArray = textToParaphrase.split(regExToFilter);
    Xeger generator = new Xeger(regexToUse);
    for (String matchedSegment : matchedPortionArray){
    String result = generator.generate(); //generates randomly (according to you!)
        textToParaphrase = textToParaphrase.replace(matchedSegment, result);
    }
    return textToParaphrase;
}
```

Cheers!